# The meaning of "lou" [Lew - the person's name]

Tags: meaning, american-english, british-english, complex-sentences, mistranslation

What is the meaning of “lou” at  0:23 in this ***[video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=Jq-ODza3Kpc)***?

Comment: Please take the time to type out the transcription.

Comment: I suspect that "Lou" is the guy's name.

Comment: His name is Lew Later as you can see here https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsTcErHg8oDvUnTzoqsYeNw

Answer (score 3):

"The question that's flyin' at me is: 'what should it be, Lou, should I go for the Playstation 5, or the XBox Series S?'"

Lou is his own name. It's the name of the man presenting the video.

Comment: Note that the man's name is actually Lew Later as shown here https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsTcErHg8oDvUnTzoqsYeNw